# My app isn't closing correctly and I'm not sure why

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-actionbar

First off, I'm using the Action Bar. When I go back to my Main class after pressing the Home option, then press the Back button, my app won't close like it should. Instead, it tries to open the activity it left from, but since I'm calling finish(), it just animates like it's switching activities and then shows my Main class. After this, I can press the Back button and properly close the app. If I don't press the Home option and use the Back button from my second activity, everything works like it should.

**Intent leading back to my Main class.**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, are you around?

Answer (score 1):

Try using intent.addflags(flags) not using intent.setflags(flags)...!!!!!

Comment: Are you finishing the previous activities before? means when u pass through previous activities, are you finishing them at end?

Comment: maybe its happening because you are not finish() ing ur main class previously before...

Comment: If I call finish() for the first activity after starting the second, then things work like they should, except that pressing the Back button in the second closes the app instead of going back to the first. I can capture the Back button in the second activity and perform the intent I have in the OP, but isn't that bad practice in Android? I shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Then override the back button and put the intent in it and finish the 2nd activity, navigate to 1st activity...!!!

Comment: I edited my previous post and mentioned that. I guess that's what I'll do.

Comment: then why u asked this question..?

Comment: Because before now I wasn't capturing the Back button in the second activity. I thought of it right before I said it to you. Also, like I said, I was trying to avoid that. Thanks for the help...!!!!!